# Bokeh - how to make multiselect dependent on select widget 'and retrieve multiselect values'?

Tags: python, bokeh

I am able to create one Select (portfolio) widget  and one dependent Multiselect (keywords) widget (keywords change based on portfolio selected). However, i am struggling to retrieve the values of Multiselect. I am not sure how to pass the populated 'keywords' widget from get_folio_terms() to the main section so that it reflects in the multiselect. Any help on this is appreciated.

PS: The code correctly displays the multiselect with the right values populated from get_folio_terms().

Here is the code:

```
keywords = MultiSelect(title="Keywords", options=[])

def get_folio_terms(attrname, old, new):
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                 user='root',
                                 password='root',
                                 db='qa_env',
                                 charset='utf8mb4',
                                 cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sqlstmt1 = "SELECT * from portfolioterms where portfolio_name = "
        sql = sqlstmt1 + "'" + portfolio.value + "';" # handle Keyerror later
        print(sql)
        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        if cursor.rowcount > 0:
            dfinput = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result)
            print(dfinput)

            keywords = MultiSelect(title="Keywords", options=list(dfinput['businessterm']))
            layout.children[1] = keywords
        else:
            keywords = MultiSelect(title="Keywords", options=[]) # reset to empty
            layout.children[1] = keywords

def update_portfolio():

    print(portfolio.value, keywords.value)


def update(attrname, old, new):
    print(keywords.value)

# set up select widget
portfolio = Select(title="portfolio", options=['ERT','Trading', 'Wealth'])
portfolio.on_change('value', get_folio_terms)

keywords.on_change('value', update)

kwbutton = Button(label='Select Keywords',width=150,button_type="success")
kwbutton.on_click(update_portfolio)
layout = column(portfolio,keywords,kwbutton)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your initial keywords widget in your function, which you then pass to the children. That works, but the global keywords is not overwritten, but remains the old one. Refer to the new one by referring directly to the child:

```
print(portfolio.value, layout.children[1].value)
```

A cleaner way of doing this is not to replace the widget with a new one, but only replacing the options:

```
keywords.options=list(dfinput['businessterm'])
```

And remove the overwrite of the children as it is not necessary anymore.

```
layout.children[1] = keywords
```

When doing it in this way, you can use you old print statements again.

```
print(portfolio.value, keywords.value)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, you saved my day!! Any idea why the print statement under update() is not getting invoked? The print statement under update_portfolio is working as expected (with your change). I didn't know we could access the values this way through .children. One of may times stackoverflow has selflessly helped people deliver value!!

Comment: its the same answer as before, the original widget  keywords has been overwritten in the get_folio_terms function and hence the update function is never called as it is not specified anymore. You could specify the callback again after creating it like you did the first time with keywords.on_change('value', update), but a cleaner solution is to not create a widget again, but just change the attribute. See the edited version of my answer.

Comment: Brilliant! it's working fine. Great to know about stuff like widget.options. Been hunting for info such as this, I knew what i was doing earlier was not clean but couldn't get the info that you gave here. I just can't thank you enough!

Comment: If you agree with my answer, could you accept it please? Thanks

Comment: I still dont see it as accepted, you can accept by clicking the accept button next to my response. Thanks

Comment: hi EddyG, pls chk now. Thanks.